# What is the fastest way to build a DataFrame piece by piece?

Tags: python, performance, memory, pandas, dataframe

I am downloading price data from bloomberg and want to build a DataFrame in the fastest and least memory intensive way.  Let's say I submit a data request to bloomberg through python for the price data for all current S&P 500 stocks from 1-1-2000 to 1-1-2013. Data is returned by ticker and then date and value, one at a time.  My current method is to create a list for the dates to be stored in and another list for the prices to be stored in, and to append a date and price to each list as they are read from the Bloomberg data request response.  Then when all the dates and prices are read for the particular ticker, I create a DataFrame for the ticker using

```
ticker_df = pd.DataFrame(price_list, index = dates_list, columns= [ticker], dtype=float)
```

I do this for each ticker, appending each ticker dataframe to a list << df_list.append(ticker_df)  >> after each ticker's data is read.  When all the ticker dataframes are made, then I combine all the individual DataFrames into one DataFrame:

```
lg_index = []
for num in range(len(df_list)):
    if len(lg_index) < len(df_list[num].index):
        lg_index = df_list[num].index  # Use the largest index for creating the result_df
result_df = pd.DataFrame(index= lg_index)
for num in range(len(df_list)):
    result_df[df_list[num].columns[0]] = df_list[num]
```

The reason why I do it this way, is because the indexes for each ticker are not identical (if a stock only IPO'd last year, etc.)

I'm guessing there must be a better way to accomplish what I'm doing here using less memory and in a faster way, I just can't think of it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure which your after, but you can `concat` a list of DataFrames:

```
pd.concat(df_list)
```

For example:

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

In [12]: pd.concat([df, df, df])
Out[12]:
   0  1
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  1  2
1  3  4
0  1  2
1  3  4

In [13]: pd.concat([df, df, df], axis=1)
Out[13]:
   0  1  0  1  0  1
0  1  2  1  2  1  2
1  3  4  3  4  3  4
```

or do an outer merge/join:

```
In [14]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]], columns=[0, 2])

In [15]: df.merge(df1, how='outer')  # do several of these
Out[15]:
   0  1   2
0  1  2   2
1  3  4 NaN
```

*See the [merge, join, concatenate section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html).*